# New iPhone, took a few nice pictures, then restored with the data of old iPhone. Pictures gone - help!

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, data-recovery

Bought new iPhone, took a few nice pictures with girlfriend, then proceeded to restore with the data of old iPhone. Pictures gone now. Can I get them back somehow?

The pictures were not backed up by iCloud or anything like it. Already tried Fonelab as a data recovery tool, but no photos showed up.

It's so stupid that the apps that I downloaded before are still there but the photos are gone... just does not make any sense! thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you able to see old pictures from the backup in Photos app on your iPhone?

Comment: What procedure did you follow to restore data from the old phone?

Comment: @bmike opened iTunes, iTunes recognized the new iPhone as new and asked me if I would like to set it up using a backup, which I then chose to do. Seems like iTunes did not do a backup prior to the restore either for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

When you restored the phone, you have changed the encryption keys on the iPhone and the old keys are gone. Unfortunately, the chances of recovering those pictures are almost 0%. It is not simply not worth trying.

The apps are there because when you've downloaded them, you have been logged in to the App Store with your account, so the information about your download/purchase was stored on Apple's server. After you have restored your phone, you have logged in again with the same account, and thus it is possible for the phone to restore your purchases/downloads.